# Multipage form in Zend Framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form2

I want to make a form divided into two steps - each on a separate page. Depending on the data given in the first step, i want to prepare some prefilled data in the second step.

Despite spending a lot of time searching in google I can not find it.

From a logical point of view, I would prefer one Zend\Form and separate fieldsets (??) than create two separate forms.

So how to do it correctly in Zend Framework 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would (I think) to have two forms, a `MyModule\Form\Step1` and a `MyModule\Form\Step2`. The `Step2` form accepts some input in the constructor which is depending on some data from step 1.

An example, you can do this with the service manager's factory:

```
'factories' => array(
  'MyModule\Form\Step1' => function($sl) {
    return new MyModule\Form\Step1;
  },
  'MyModule\Form\Step2' => function($sl) {
    $request = $sl->get('Request');
    $data    = $request->getPost();
    return new MyModule\Form\Step2($data);
  }
),
```

If you `GET` the page where the first one is displayed, then you `POST` to the second page and finally `POST` to the last page. During construction of the second form, you use the POST data and populate/construct the data as needed.

Comment: Thank you;) From what I see, it can be achieve only by using such hacks/methods. Too bad that there is no method to do it simplier and "more clean"r;)